# Large object recognition in Vuforia

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I have to admit a very large object in Vuforia, having the ability to get close and not lose recognition.

The object is static and can track from afar.

Is there any system that can with a static camera position it, and with a camera phone to navigate close to the object?

Sorry if I have not explained well.

Answer (score -2):

Extended Tracking allows the tracking a degree of persistence once a target has been detected. As the target goes out of view, Vuforia uses other information from the environment to infer the target position by visually tracking the environment. Vuforia builds a map around the target specifically for this purpose and assumes that both the environment and target are largely static.

Extended Tracking can significantly enhance two kinds of user experience:

Game or game-like experiences with a large amount of dynamic content that requires the user to point the device away from the target as the user follows the content
Visualizations of large objects like furniture, appliances, large home furnishings and even architectural models at the right scale and perspective

Learn more about : https://developer.vuforia.com/library/articles/Training/Extended-Tracking